# Is it possible to define an variable as base url on nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

what I trying to do is define a base url variable for my API which is able to be called everywhere on nuxt app. for example I'm trying to call an image from my API storage like bellow

```
<img :src="`${baseUrl}/****/****.png`">
```

Assuming I can define the variable, so I don't need to change every img url when the API domain changed. or I would be very thankful for introduce any better way to calling image from API storage. btw I'm using Laravel as the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the [runtimeConfig](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#runtimeconfig) for this, `publicRuntimeConfig` or `privateRuntimeConfig` depending on your requirement

*nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: 'https://nuxtjs.org'
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    apiSecret: 'something_private'
  }
}
```

Once added this variable will be available under `$config` across your Nuxt app like below

*In templates*

```
<template>
  <p>Our Url is: {{ $config.baseURL}}</p>
</template>
```

*In places where you use the context* (plugins, asyncData etc)

```
<script>
  asyncData ({ $config: { baseURL } }) {
    const posts = await fetch(`${baseURL}/posts`)
      .then(res => res.json())
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so when i call it in one of my component would be like this $config.baseURL?

Comment: Yep, Updated the answer with usage examples

Comment: i see , so its can be used as plugin